# How to copy generated string and paste in config file in linux

Tags: linux, shell, command-line

Noob question.

I am generating a hash using a script. Now I want to use the hash as a password in my tomcat users file.

How should I go about this without using any GUI, since I am working on a server.

Answer (score 0):

You're encrypting a password, yes?

```
printf "%s" "password_string" | md5sum | cut -d" " -f1
```

You need the printf invocation to ensure a newline does not get appended to the password.

There's also `sha1sum`, if you prefer to use that. These commands, I believe, are part of the `openssl` package.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I am encrypting a password, but am using the shell script digest.sh provided by tomcat. Its output is  as follows : password:hash

Comment: Do you still need assistance?

Comment: yes, I already have a hashed password. I just don't know how to copy it and then paste it in a config file

Comment: It's an xml file. But I how is that relevant?

Comment: Obviously relevant. You can't just append the password onto the end of an XML file. What XPATH is the encrypted password supposed to have? Do you know how to do that? I can't tell from your questions or comments.